# VMWare ESXi 4 not manageble from LOCAL subnet

Tags: vmware-esxi, subnet

I have an ESXi 4.1.0u3 standalone (clean install). Only vmnic0 is connected to management/clients. vmnic1 is temporarily connected to another network for transfering data. vmnic2 and 3 are teamed to the iSCSI on a seperate VLAN. I can manage the ESXi with the client from a different subnet, but not from it's own subnet. I can ping it from it's own subnet, but can't even access the webinterface.

ESXi adresses:
vmnic0: 10.3.5.20/255.255.254.0 (/23)
vmnic1: 10.12.240.18/255.255.255.0 (/24)
vmnic2+3: 10.3.2.20/255.255.255.0 (/24)
gw: 10.3.5.254

Client address which can't manage:
vSwitch0 (vmnic0) connected: 10.3.5.100/255.255.254.0

Client address which can manage:
Over Cisco Anyconnect VPN (ASA5505): 10.3.3.11/255.255.255.0

Switch is a stacked Dell PC6224 without VLANs (except iSCSI VLAN). ASA is connected with a single link to switch and has IP 10.3.5.254/23 and traffic between different hosts on same interface allowed (not that this should matter)

I'm stumped:
- can ping from local subnet
- can't access https from local subnet
- can't access with vSphere client from local subnet
- can do all of the above from any other subnet

Where to look?

Comment: Forgot to add: communication to VM's on local subnet is no problem at all

Comment: Do the arp tables make sense? Are there any routes on any of the systems? Are there firewall rules active? Can you verify which interface the management tools (web) are binding to?

Comment: Brain storm... Double check your vSwitch configuration, and where the service console(s) is/are.  Double check subnet masks.  Check the host firewall.

Comment: service console is on vswitch0/vmnic0.

Comment: arp table seems off. I get the same MAC for the VMWare and my Cisco ASA

Comment: Yes, it was the ARP table. The ASA has ProxyARP on the Inside interface enabled by default. Somehow this was the cause to get a wrong ARP reply.

Comment: @adric please create an answer so I can credit you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do some basic network troubleshooting before returning to the applications that are driving you to distraction.

Do the arp tables make sense? Are there any routes on any of the systems? Are there firewall rules active? Can you verify which interface the management tools (web) are binding to?